# How well can a MS Access form be themed?

Tags: ms-access, ui-design

In around 12 months I intend providing my users with a web-based business management system (our corporate infrastructure will take that long to be ready).

As a stepping stone, an MS Access solution is being developed.

I have a useable web-UI defined for my app, typical modern html5/css theme.  To ease the user's transition to the web-based solution next year I'd like to make the MS Access solution look as close to the web-UI as I can.  So I'd like to replicate the colors & styles used.

But, I don't know how I should aim for.

Can anybody provide any links/examples of MS Access forms that approach modern levels of web-design?  I guess I'm thinking about rounded corners, gradients, "call to action" buttons.

I'm currently unsure whether I'll be targeting 2003 or 2007.  I really doubt it will be 2010 :-(

Cheers,
Ian

Comment: How does consistency of a detail such as rounded corners ease (in any meaningful way) the users' transition from your temporary Access solution to its web replacement?

Comment: @HansUp - I guess it's part of general look & feel. Insignificant on their own, I imagine the contributing factors add up an over all feel.

Comment: Consider focusing on functional consistency but intentionally ignore consistency of the fine aesthetic details.  Then, when you transition the users from Access to the web replacement, you give them an opportunity to think "not only does this do everything the old application did, but it's simply gorgeous too!"

Comment: Thanks @HansUp - nice perspective

Answer (score 3):

Access 2010 supports themes and in fact behind the scenes they are based on CSS style sheets. So Access 2010 the forms and buttons etc. can be fully "web looking" and that includes hover effects.

In fact you can even export the SharePoint web site theme, and import it into Access now. (I don't know if you can edit the sheets directly - but you should be able to).

Here are some of the design surface options:

[image]

So an Access form now looks like this:

[image]

Note the new "web" navigation control on the left side. While you can place plane Jane buttons on that form, you can as noted place round buttons, oval, and set the hover effects along with a shadow effect. So how much "web like" you want is certainly possible.

While most of these new "web" features and effects are for the new web publishing ability in Access 2010, these features also work in client forms also. In the following video you see these forms run as "client", but at the halfway point then I switch to running the forms 100% in a web browser and they look the same in that web browser.

Access running on the web video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Comment: Thanks Albert.  Unfortunately there's a strong chance my users won't get 2010 this decade :-(   Thanks also for taking the effort to include the screenshots of such an application.

Comment: @ianmayo, Users can use MS Access run-time if they don't have office suite

Comment: Is there a link that you took this image from or did you create it yourself? I'm trying to do a similar project as ianmayo was and am hoping to find a website with access form design suggestions.